# In unit test how can I compare original object with scope copy and avoid angular $$hashKey

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I can explain my question in one image.

[image: In unit test how can I compare original object with scope copy and avoid angular $$hashKey]

In my unit test after some manipulations I want to check that `$scope.data` (first log message) is equal to original `data` object (second log message). I use mocha + chai and

```
expect(innerScope.data).to.deep.equal(data);
```

It is used in directive, so angular adds $$hashKey's to each object and of course my expectation is wrong. How can I test it in other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only 2 ways I can think of:

1: Delete the $$hashKey property from the innerScope.data objects before the comparison:

```
innerScope.data.forEach(function (o) { delete o.$$hashKey });
expect(innerScope.data).to.deep.equal(data);
```

2: Loop through the objects and test that each object in innerScope.data contains the corresponding object in the original data, this will ignore any extra properties on the innerScope.data objects:

```
for (var i = 0; i < innerScope.data.length; i++) {
    expect(innerScope.data[i]).to.contain(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: You can also use [angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) method on both objects to produce string without `$$hashKey`

Comment: var clean = JSON.parse( angular.toJson( dirty ) );

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not a new question but the jasmine.objectContaining method would help here [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Partial_Matching_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.objectContaining%3C/code%3E)